Gmail FBL Customer Complaint Data
I am looking to implement FBL for Gmail so we can get the data of customers with Gmail addresses who submit complaints and stop sending them commercial emails. As per my understanding and documentation, this is not a standard functionality.
Can you share with us how we can do it?
Regards,
Shari

This is technically not possible. A number of ISPs share their complaints with ESPc (SFMC included)[source]:

Bluetie (Excite), Comcast, Cox, Fastmail, Microsoft Hotmail, Italia Online, La Poste, Liberty Global, Locaweb, Mail.ru, OpenSRS (Tucows), Rackspace (Mailtrust), Seznam, Synacor, Telenor, Telstra, Terra, UOL (Brazil), USA.net, XS4ALL, and Yandex

As you can see, we don't have Gmail on that list. This is because Gmail doesn't share complain data outside of their own environment, leaving you with Google Postmaster Tools as the only access to (aggregated) complaint data [source].

DMARC reports (aggregate or forensic) - do they not flow to MC end-user (the customer  corp) ?

This I don't know @identigral - but I doubt you can use DMARC reports for complaint feedback from ISP to ESP?

While not a direct replacement of FBL, you'd be notified of issues. GMail has a good explainer

I think these are different issues (other senders are trying to send emails from my domain - and being rejected as per DMARC policy), and not recipients complaining over my (otherwise legitimate) emails to them being seen as spam. Or am I wrong here, @identigral?

You're correct - if the email comes makes it to the mailbox and recipient tags it as spam, DMARC won't catch it. But mailbox providers (e.g. Gmail) tagging it as spam should trigger a report via DMARC. The OP's question is somewhat of a XY problem, the correct goal would be to cover both scenarios - one scenario is attainable via DMARC.

@identigral the scenario caught by DMARC should IMHO not have any impact on Subscriber status and spam complaints in SFMC. DMARC issues are caused by other senders spoofing your sender domain, without proper authentication. It should correctly be rejected by Gmail, but is not caused by your own emails being seen as "spammy". The latter should indeed result in feedback loop telling you so, allowing you to unsubscribe the specific recipient, hence avoiding additional spam reports from this subscriber.

We were thinking that if recipient tags it as spam often and (on that basis) provider auto-routes later messages to spam, DMARC would get triggered...but this is incorrect, you're right. If DMARC would know about spam, spammers would take advantage.
